# How do I fix "undefined variable: void" error loading scilab BackDoor

Tags: octave, scilab

I'm attempting to install sci cosim for Octave, and to do so I need to install scilab, and BackDoor, however, with BackDoor installed I get the following error upon starting scilab:

```
atomsLoad: An error occurred while loading 'BackDoor-0.22':
exec: error on line #46: "Undefined variable: void"
```

Comment: It is unclear - which Scilab version do you have? How did you installed it (as deb or as binary archive extracted somewhere)? Do you mean this [BackDoor](https://atoms.scilab.org/toolboxes/BackDoor) atoms package? Did you tried to contact atoms developer?

Answer (score 0):

For Scilab 6.0.x you can use the following command to fix the issue:

`sed -i 's/openBackDoor(void\* pvApiCtx);/openBackDoor();/' ~/.Scilab/scilab-6.0.?/atoms/BackDoor/0.22/etc/backdoor.start`

it changes incorrect line 46 from `openBackDoor(void* pvApiCtx);` to correct `openBackDoor();`.

And then the toolbox will load on next Scilab start:

> ```
> Startup execution:
>  loading initial environment
>
> Start Toolbox BackDoor
>   Load macros
>   Load gateways
>   Load help
>   Opening back door
> ```

Note: I have never used this toolbox, read please read its documentation by yourself.